# jquery post encodeURIComponent and textarea line break issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am using encodeURIComponent to send value to php script

?txtAra = encodeURIComponent($("#textAra").val())

I saw in firebug it sends line break as `%0A`, in php script i am using

```
$txtA = $_POST['txtAra'];
```

and php mail function, in email i sees as test\n\n\ntest\n\n\ntest

How do i make \n as normal line break in mail?

i tried str_replace and nl2br, still same.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

What header type you are setting in mail ?
text 
or html ?